# make uploaded files available for download in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, download

I am creating a website for our community. It will have the capability of uploading pdf files and make those files available for download. I uploaded the files in my post and I want to make those files downloadable on the post where I uploaded it. Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this?

Comment: what files ? images ? pdf ? zip ? download as a link ? what theme ? have you tried to search for plugins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to WordPress dashboard > add media > select files > upload your pdf > copy the link of pdf file. And add that link into your post.